# Can anybody give me the original ssh.plist file for OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: macos, ssh, plist

I was trying to modify my `ssh.plist` file, but as a noob I overwrote my backup file with the modified one.

I am looking for the content of the original file from the install.

Can anybody give it to me?

Comment: what ssh plist file? where is it located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Disabled</key>
<true/>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.openssh.sshd</string>
<key>Program</key>
<string>/usr/libexec/sshd-keygen-wrapper</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/sbin/sshd</string>
    <string>-i</string>
</array>
<key>SHAuthorizationRight</key>
<string>system.preferences</string>
<key>Sockets</key>
<dict>
    <key>Listeners</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Bonjour</key>
        <array>
            <string>ssh</string>
            <string>sftp-ssh</string>
        </array>
        <key>SockServiceName</key>
        <string>ssh</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/dev/null</string>
<key>inetdCompatibility</key>
<dict>
    <key>Wait</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody give me the original ssh.plist file for OS X?

You can also find it at Apple's opensource.apple.com at [launchd-ssh.plist](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-166/launchd-ssh.plist):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.openssh.sshd</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/libexec/sshd-keygen-wrapper</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/sshd</string>
        <string>-i</string>
    </array>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Listeners</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SockServiceName</key>
            <string>ssh</string>
            <key>Bonjour</key>
            <array>
                <string>ssh</string>
                <string>sftp-ssh</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/dev/null</string>
        <key>SHAuthorizationRight</key>
        <string>system.preferences</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Notice Apple uses `/usr/libexec/sshd-keygen-wrapper` as the program. If I recall correctly, that generates host keys if needed and then starts the actual daemon.

---

> what ssh plist file? where is it located?

The plist file is located at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`.

You can stop the server with:

`sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

You can start the server with:

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

---

Apple also uses ancient versions of programs and libraries, so there's value in upgrading. For example, both OpenSSL and OpenSSH have both been updated due to security bugs.

You have a couple of options if you want to upgrade. First, you can build and install OpenSSH yourself by following [Building OpenSSH for OS X?](https://superuser.com/q/961349) on Super User. Second, you can use a package tool like Brew, Fink or Macports to install it.

If you use the package manager, then you will probably want to disable Apple's OpenSSH, add a new launch daemon to start the port's gear, and use the port's configuration files.